# What is an "abstract noun"?

Tags: article

Hammer's German Grammar and Usage states, "German typically uses an article with abstract nouns." But how does one identify an abstract noun? For instance,

> Gestern wurde Ben angerufen, während er bei der Arbeit war.

*Arbeit* appears to be "abstract" here. But he has a specific and concrete job. Or is this a set, idiomatic phrase?

Comment: Maybe a non-abstract noun describes something physical, such as »der Baum« or »das Haus«. In English there would be a difference between “I am at school” and “I am at the school”, where “school” is the abstract noun of the classes you're taking at the physical, non-abstract building “the school“. Hence it's stressed in an English (?) grammar of the German language. To Germans, saying »Nomen die abstrakte Dinge beschreiben haben üblicherweise einen Artikel«, is like saying “water is wet” ...

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Concrete_nouns_and_abstract_nouns) Wikipedia passage seems relevant.

Comment: "Ich esse gerne Brot" - is an abstract noun, too, even if you cannot eat abstract bread.

Answer (score 1):

"Bei der Arbeit" translates to "at work" in German. It refers to work in general, not a specific job. This example illustrates that German uses a definite article whereas English does not use an article.

Comment: This example just illustrates that in this example German uses a definite article whereas English does not use an article :) For *I'm an Architect* but *Ich bin Architekt*.

Comment: One could argue that *an architect* is not abstract in the way *work* is.

Comment: OK, but exactly _how_ would one so argue, that an architect is not abstract and work is?

Comment: @user44591: you can touch an architect?